# Find responses with no notification and with no prior responses for the same endpoint with an notification created less than 1 hour ago

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Background**

As a user I can setup an endpoint with an expected response status and then tell the web service to ping this endpoint at a given interval, e.g., every 30 minutes.

**Problem**

I want to find all responses that have a `status` that isn't matching the `expected_status` of the associated endpoint. For every response I then generate a notification row in the database. If there is a previous response row for the same endpoint that have an associated notification row less than one hour ago, I want to ignore this response row.

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate what I'm after. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0927b/1.

In my fiddle, I'd expected the SQL query to return the responses with ID 2 and 5. As you can see, I get back ID 2, 4 and 5.

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Why would it not include response 4? After all it doesn't have a notification, and its status is 500 (expected 200).

Comment: Because there is a prior response with an associated notification created less than one hour ago. I only want to include the response if it was at least one hour ago since a response with a notification for the same endpoint was created.

Comment: When you say __ago__, what do you mean exactly? Ago as in time ago from the current moment? Or ago as in time prior to a specific response's creation time?

Comment: Ago as in time prior to a specific response's creation time. I.e., if a response with an associated notification was created at 23.30 and there exists two more responses for the same endpoint without associated notifications at 00.00 and 00.30. I'd expect only the last one to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use NOT EXISTS looking for rows matching the condition you want to filter by, or LEFT JOIN on a subselect again with the rows matching the condition you want to filter by.

The first case is likely to perform better when the condition is unusual, since the test is done only when the other tests failed (status plus absence of notification):

```
    SELECT e.id, q.id, r.id, n.id, r.status, e.expected_status, n.response_id
      FROM endpoints e
      JOIN requests q on (q.endpoint_id = e.id)
      JOIN responses r on (r.request_id = q.id)
 LEFT JOIN notifications n on (n.response_id = r.id)
     WHERE r.status <> e.expected_status AND n.response_id IS NULL AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM requests q2
                       JOIN responses r2 ON (r2.request_id = q2.id)
                       JOIN notifications n2 ON (n2.response_id = r2.id)
                       WHERE q2.endpoint_id = e.id AND
                             r2.created_at < r.created_at AND
                             r2.created_at > r.created_at - INTERVAL '1h')
```

But in cases where the condition is the norm, you may benefit from the second case:

```
    SELECT e.id, q.id, r.id, n.id, r.status, e.expected_status, n.response_id
      FROM endpoints e
      JOIN requests q ON (q.endpoint_id = e.id)
      JOIN responses r ON (r.request_id = q.id)
 LEFT JOIN notifications n ON (n.response_id = r.id)
 LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT q2.endpoint_id, r2.created_at
        FROM requests q2
        JOIN responses r2 ON (r2.request_id = q2.id)
        JOIN notifications n2 ON (n2.response_id = r2.id)
           ) prev ON (prev.endpoint_id = e.id AND prev.created_at < r.created_at AND prev.created_at > r.created_at - INTERVAL '1h')
     WHERE r.status <> e.expected_status AND
           n.response_id IS NULL AND
           prev.endpoint_id IS NULL
```

Comment: By the way, you have a problem in your data. The responses before midnight are on the same date as the responses after midnight, but they should be one day prior. You can fix it (on the test data) by running `update responses set created_at = created_at - interval '1d' where created_at::time > '23:00';` prior to running these queries.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the SQL fiddle to reflect that.